# Can I enable Live Chat on a regular app or only on a console?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, chat

I am trying to enable Live Agent for my org, and the only way I can find to do it is by creating a new console and adding it to this console. When I go to the set up for existing apps or try to create a new regular app, the option to add Live Agent is not even present. The console set up is very different then a regular app and I try not to switch things up on my users if it isn't absolutely necessary. Is there a way to make Live Agent available on regular apps?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is no longer possible. Live Agent is only available in the Salesforce console.